# Obtain the maximum frequency only for each factor

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

So this gives the entire list with what I needed:

```
max <- function(x) {
    n <- data.frame(x)
    factored <- n[sapply(n, is.factor)]
    dt_res = data.frame()

    for (i in 1:ncol(factored)) {

        dt_temp = data.frame(t(table(factored[, i])))
        dt_temp$Var1 = names(factored)[i]
        dt_res = rbind(dt_res, dt_temp)

    }

    names(dt_res) = c("Factors", "Categories", "Frequency")

    return(dt_res)
}
```

How do I get the maximum frequency for each factors? With the diamond set, I get

```
Factors Categories Frequency
cut       Fair      1610 
cut       Good      4906 
cut    Very Good    12082 
cut      Premium    13791 
cut      Ideal      21551 
color      D         6775 
color      E         9797 
color      F         9542 
color      G        11292 
color      H        8304 
color      I        5422 
color      J        2808
```

And the category for clarity, but I want it to return this:

```
Factors Categories Frequency
cut      Ideal      21551 
color      G        11292 
clarity    SI1      13065
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a change to your function, if you want to use it. (After all, it's *your* solution.)

```
max <- function(x){

    [... your code ...]
    [... then, between 'names' and 'return' ...]

    names(dt_res) = c("Factors", "Categories", "Frequency")
    dt_res <- lapply(split(dt_res, dt_res$Factors), function(x) x[which.max(x$Frequency), ])
    dt_res <- do.call(rbind, dt_res)
    row.names(dt_res) <- NULL
    return(dt_res)
}

max(diamonds)
#  Factors Categories Frequency
#1 clarity        SI1     13065
#2   color          G     11292
#3     cut      Ideal     21551
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of `dplyr` and `tidyr` verbs

Data

```
data <- diamonds
```

Solution

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
select(data, cut, color, clarity) %>%   # dplyr - select relevant columns
  gather(key, value) %>%                # tidyr - gather into long format
  group_by(key) %>%                     # dplyr - group by column name
  count(value) %>%                      # dplyr - table-like function
  top_n(1)                              # dplyr - filter for top row by group
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   key [3]
      # key value     n
    # <chr> <chr> <int>
# 1 clarity   SI1 13065
# 2   color     G 11292
# 3     cut Ideal 21551
```

*Edit* Choosing other columns

To choose other columns, change this line `select(data, cut, color, clarity)`. For instance, `select(data, depth, table, price)`

To use all the columns in `diamonds`, replace `select(data, cut, color, clarity) %>%` with `data %>%`

Comment: I was planning to use it in my function, so it will not work for other columns that are not cut, color, and clarity. I've tried dt_temp = data.frame(max(t(table(factored[,i])))) only to get the factors and frequency, not the category.

Comment: I would avoid for loops whenever possible. You can choose other columns if you wish. See my edited answer.